# Show just the first row of a table (stored in globals)

Tags: globals, table-field

Morning Craft folks, I've had a look and play but can't seem to find an answer for this.

I have a global variable with a company's various phone numbers in, stored in a table field.

The table shows the city, then the phone number for the company's numbers.

For the navigation, I want to show just the first phone number in the table.

`.first()` and `.limit(1)` don't seem to work in this situation.

```
<li>
    {% if companyDetails.telephoneNumbers | length %}
        {% for row in companyDetails.telephoneNumbers %}
            <a href="#contact-us" role="menuitem" aria-selected="false">{{ row.number }}</a>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    <span>Call us</a></span>
</li>
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`first()` and `limit()` are methods of the `ElementCriteriaModel`. Since a table is not an element, but just a plain array, you should use array filters.

So use Twig's [`slice`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html) filter instead.

```
<li>
    {% if companyDetails.telephoneNumbers | length %}
        {% for row in companyDetails.telephoneNumbers | slice(0, 1) %}
        <a href="#contact-us" role="menuitem" aria-selected="false">{{ row.number }}</a>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    <span>Call us</a></span>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks Bob, this worked great. I saw the slice else where but misunderstood its purpose.